# Cakephp 3.6. How to call a helpers query from a controller?

Tags: ajax, cakephp-3.0, helper

I have on my homepage a small search form with a list of categories.
I use a helper to query the database to get all categories. This is fine and works great.

Now I want to update the categories select with an updated list of categories based on a performed search.

That means, I would need to call query inside the helper with a given $variable to run a new query and to return new data.

But this is my concern now.
I can't call a helper from within the PagesController, right?

So what is the right way to
- have a helper call to use on the fly in all views selecting DB Data?
- address an ajax call to a controller and to use the query from the helper?

Any advice will be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You code needs to be moved in a Table class and not in a Helper class, if you need it both in the Controller and the View.

**Long Answer:**

The code you have created in your helper needs to be moved in the relevant Table class and that will fetch the data.

Then in both your view and the controller you will use the new method you created in your Table class.

For example in your CategoriesTable class you can add a method called:

```php
public function fetchCategoryData(){
   //TODO: Custom code that will fetch the category data like...
   //return $this->find();
}

public function updateCategoyData($args){
   //TODO: Custom code to update your category data
}
```

Now, in either the View or the Controller you can use this

```
$Categories = TableRegistry::get('Categories');

$Categories->fetchCategoryData();
//or
$Categories->updateCategoryData();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will go this way! Luckely I ended up with this issue right at the beginning :-) Thanks!!!!